# How to iterate into a list into a tuple

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration, tuples

I am writing a program where I have a bunch of tuples in a list like this:

`[('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1'), ('a03', '01-24-2011', 's2')` etc.

The tuples are the format

```
(animal ID, date(month, day, year), station# )
```

I do not know how to access the information about the month only.

I have tried:

```
months = []    
for item in list:
    for month in item:
        if month[0] not in months:
            months.append(month[0])
```

I am working in python 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
L = [('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1'), ('a03', '01-24-2011', 's2')]
for animal, date, station in L:
    month, day, year = date.split('-')
    print("animal ID {} in month {} at station {}".format(animal, month, station))
```

Output:

```
animal ID a01 in month 01 at station s1
animal ID a03 in month 01 at station s2
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to get the second item of the tuple, which is a string, then get the first two characters of the string. Those characters describe the month.

I'll go through the process step by step.

Let's say you have a list called `data`:

```
data = [('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1'), ('a03', '01-24-2011', 's2')]
```

Take the first item:

```
item = data[0]
```

The value of `item` is the tuple `('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1')`.

Take the second element of `item`:

```
date = item[1]
```

The value of `date` is the string `'01-24-2011'`.

Take the first two characters of `date`:

```
month = date[:2]
```

The value of `month` is the string `01`. You can convert this into an integer:

```
month = int(month)
```

Now the value of `month` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions:

```
data = [('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1'), ('a03', '01-24-2011', 's2')]

months = [item[1].split('-')[0] for item in data]

print(months)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_list = [('a01', '01-24-2011', 's1'), ('a03', '01-24-2011', 's2')]
>>> [ x for x in map(lambda x:x[1].split('-')[0],my_list) ]
['01', '01']
```

you can use map and lambda

Comment: I find the list comprehension proposed by gg.kaspersky to be nicer compared to map/lambda: [item[1].split('-')[0] for item in my_list]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a unique list of months and order does not matter use a set:

```
months = list({date.split("-",1)[0] for _, date, _ in l})
```